# TFS cannot track changes when it is offline & Go Online is clicked next

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm working on *VS2012 & Team Explorer for VS 2012*.

The problem I have is, if in case the *TFS* goes down, my solution would be offline & any changes I make would not show up in the Pending changes window.

I have checked for ways by which I can make *TFS* track the changes but none of them helped.

**Things I tried:**

1. **Go online** option in the context menu -> It displays a window with a list of all the objects & I would have to go through each one of them to identify which objects I would like to track which becomes tedious.
2. I tried installing the **TFSGoOffline extension** present [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e7e28e0d-02a2-4497-bcdc-5953ba23f7dc), but result same as mentioned in the above point.
   Can I, by any way make *TFS* track the changes if *TFS* goes down or I want to work offline & then go online?

Comment: Are you using a local or server workspace? They have different behavior: local are best option for working disconnected.

Comment: @GiulioVian: I'm using **local workspace**. To be more precise, I have _mapped the solution onto my local hard disk_. It is this solution that is mapped/connected to TFS.

Comment: @Ankit thank you for clarifying; what you described is not a local workspace, necessarily, as having mapped working folders is a property of both local and server workspaces.  It sounds like you want local but have server.

Comment: @EdwardThomson: Yes, indeed. What you said is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you making use of server or local workspace? This is a new concept introduced in TFS 2012, just to tackle the same problem that you are facing (tracking changes when TFS is offline). This is an excerpt from this [LINK](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/11/02/local-workspaces-in-tfs-2012.aspx), which gives you a good explanation about Server vs local workspace:

> Before Team Foundation Server 2012, all workspaces were considered
>   "Server" workspaces; in essence, in a Server workspace, when a file's
>   retrieved from TFS, TFS tracks which version of the file's on the
>   local machine, and the file is set to read-only. By setting the file
>   to read-only, the server is able to track exactly which version of the
>   file is stored locally.
>
> One drawback to Server workspaces is the ability to work offline from
>   TFS. Each version of TFS has made strides to make offline work easier,
>   but, by design, Server workspaces work best with an online connection
>   into TFS.
>
> TFS 2012 changes up the workspace options. Server workspaces are still
>   available, and work exactly has they have in previous versions.
>   However, TFS 2012 now contains a new type of workspace, called a Local
>   workspace. Again, this is an oversimplification, but in a Local
>   workspace, all the files are read/write, not read-only. The meta-data
>   about the files is stored in a hidden folder in the root of the
>   workspace, which allows edits, renames and deletes to be done locally
>   without any communication to the server.

If you edit your current workspace, you will be able to know whether you are using Server or Local workspace now. Check the images towards the end of the document.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a ton! That was it. I have another question. When I opt for local workspaces, the **Check Out Lock permissions** (i.e. If I check out a file, another developer would not be able to check out the same file until I check In or Undo my changes) are no longer enforceable. Is there a way by which I can employ the Check Out Lock on objects/files & have a feature like local workspaces?

Comment: Then post a new question: don't use the comment for this.

Answer (score 0):

When I am working and I lost connection, once I get the connection back again, I do a couple of things.

First, close my VS and re-open again.

If this doesn´t help,then from the `TEAM menu -> Connect to TFS`. This way he will re-read all your folders and my pending changes appear in the Team Explorer window.

You can maybe try to right click and `Check In Pending Changes`, maybe this way, TFS re-read again your changes.

As I said, for me this couple of things works ;) I hope that for you too

Comment: Then so sorry. I can´t help more. Good luck Ankit!

Comment: Above answer may help you.